# Data cleaning in bigquery sql changing from float to integer

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table where I want to alter the values in the columns from float to integer and replace the values and keep it as string. How would I best do this?

The table is as follows:

| id | discount | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | dettol soap |
| 2 | 10.0 | dettol soap green |
| 3 | 0 | dettol soap red |
| 4 | x | dettol soap blue |
| 5 |  | dettol soap yellow |
| 6 | 5 | dettol soap beige |
| 9 | 13.3210282172312131 | dettol soap white |

I want to clean the discount table into the same table

| id | discount | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | dettol soap |
| 2 | 10 | dettol soap green |
| 3 | 0 | dettol soap red |
| 4 | 0 | dettol soap blue |
| 5 | 0 | dettol soap yellow |
| 6 | 5 | dettol soap beige |
| 9 | 13 | dettol soap white |

What I have is
select
id
, cast(cast(discount as integer) as string)
, product
from table

How do you do a replace non numbers and blanks into 0 and decimals into integer and cast as string and replace the values into the current table?

Comment: You're not converting from a `FLOAT`, as `'X'` isn't a `FLOAT`. You're converting from a string, likely a `VARCHAR()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```sql
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(CAST(SAFE_CAST(x AS FLOAT64) AS INT64), 0) AS STRING) AS discount 
  FROM UNNEST(['10', '10.0', '0', 'x', '', '5', '13.3210282172312131']) x;
```

Or, you can try it with a regular expression.

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^[0-9]+'), '0') discount
  FROM UNNEST(['10', '10.0', '0', 'x', '', '5', '13.3210282172312131']) x;
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select * 
  replace(
    format('%.0f', ifnull(safe_cast(discount AS float64), 0))
  as discount)
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]